# Hide a folder from a QFileSystemModel

Tags: c++, qt, directory, qfilesystemmodel

I would like to know how to hide a specific folder in a treeView with `QFileSystemModel`.

I know that we can filter folders to show only some files using `setFilter` but I don't know how to filter a folder.

I want to display folders except one. I know the name of this folder so I can choose it by the name.

Does anyone know how to hide/remove this folder from the list please?

Comment: Did you try `QFileSystemModel::setNameFilters()`?

Comment: Yes I already use QFileSystemModel::setNameFilters() to filter files by extension into a folder. So when I apply the filter I see only files with the extension I want. In my case I don't want to see a folder named "foldername".

Answer (score 3):

The filters can use wildcards, but those wildcards are optional. You're free to use the filters to filter out a non-wildcard name.

```cpp
QStringList filters;
filters << "*.badext" << "foldername";
model->setNameFilters(filters);
```

If you want tighter control over it - for example, to only filter out folder with a given name, and not a file with a given name, then you need to implement a `QSortFilterProxyModel`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes I want to filter out folder with a given name. So could you give me clues to implement this with a `QSortFilterProxyModel` please? I checked this class and I didn't find what I am looking for.